# Can I use components of a web app with a React Native app

Tags: react-native, web, components

I am trying to build an app in react native. The app was originally built in unity, but due to performance reasons. It was decided the app should be rebuilt in react native. The app currently has a web app also and I am wondering if there is a way when that the react native app can use some components from the web app.

I tried to google this problem, but I only find articles about using components between react native and react native web. I do not know what the web app was built with, but I am almost certain that it was not react native web.

Answer (score 0):

What component are you trying to use?

Because if it's a pure unity I think there are some libraries who are not available on a mobile device, so you can't use it.
I have in mid some C++ libraries or third part one to use the sound.

Comment: The current **mobile** app is built in pure unity, but the **web** app is not from my understanding. I believe the **web** app is built in HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I can ask for more information, if it is needed.

Comment: You can maybe use a webview to wrap all the web part https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview for a quick win but there is a chance to lose some specific unity interactions